# Slack bolt ack() with errors

Tags: slack-api

I am trying to implement email validation in Slack modal.
documentation is here.
https://slack.dev/bolt-js/concepts#acknowledge
If I enter valid email, it works well.
And If I enter invalid email, it occurs error.
[image]

I believe that it occurs because of ack() with errors.
So, I want to ask. What is the meaning of "name": "email_address", in below code?

```
// Regex to determine if this is a valid email
let isEmail = /^[\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4}$/
// This uses a constraint object to listen for dialog submissions with a callback_id of ticket_submit 
app.action({ callback_id: 'ticket_submit' }, async ({ action, ack }) => {
  // it’s a valid email, accept the submission
  if (isEmail.test(action.submission.email)) {
    await ack();
  } else {
    // if it isn’t a valid email, acknowledge with an error
    await ack({
      errors: [{
        "name": "email_address",
        "error": "Sorry, this isn’t a valid email"
      }]
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution.
block_1 is block_id.

```
await ack({
  response_action: 'errors',
  errors: {
    block_1: 'Sorry, this isn’t a valid email',
  },
});
```